# Why can't I read a TEXT attribute from SQLITE TABLE in the application?

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I this table in a **Sqlite db3**:

[image: Table definition]

with data in it which I can read with a simple query in **SQLite Studio SQL editor**:

```
Select Testo FROM Contenuto
```

[image: Query result]

As you can see i only need the Testo attribute.

When I try to do the same query or try to retrive all the attributes (Id, IDSezione, Indice, Testo), in my **xamarin Forms Application**, the result have all of them but Testo. (Contenuti is a List of Contenuto objects)

[image: Application result]

This is my DB method:

```
public Task<List<Contenuto>> GetContenutoAsync(int idsezione)
{
        return Database.Table<Contenuto>().Where(i => i.IDSezione == idsezione).ToListAsync();
}
```

So I'm wondering what is the problem and if someone can help me.
I thought it was a size limit dimension but it do the same with just a character instead of a long text as I need.

#### class

```
[Table(nameof(Contenuto))]
public class Contenuto
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public int IDSezione { get; set; }

    public int Indice { get; set; }

    public string Testo { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks, Riccardo

Comment: where is `Contenuto` defined?

Comment: In a class in the shared project

Comment: please post the code for that class so WE CAN SEE IT

Comment: @Jason i have edited the answer

Comment: are you positive that you are reading your pre-populated db and not a blank copy?  Using a pre-populated db takes some non-trivial setup.  Can you read the entire table without the WHERE clause to verify that you are getting the right number of rows?

Comment: @Jason (As you can see in the 2nd image) I tried your suggestion but I got the same result all attributes but Testo.

Comment: the 2nd image shows the result from SQLite Studio, not from your app

Comment: @Jason sorry I mean the 3rd one

Comment: you are still querying a single row.  I'm suggesting you query the entire table to validate that all the rows are there.  `return Database.Table<Contenuto>()` WITHOUT the WHERE clause

Comment: @Jason yeah btw I found the problem it was a wrong name: the "Testo" column is actually named "Contenuto" and this is because the DB in the Android project isn't updated...

Comment: @Riccardo, it seems that you have solved your issue now? If yes, please give one reply with you solution, and mark your reply as answer, it is beneficial to other community members who face the same issue, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So this is how I resolve my problem:

Originally the `Testo` attribute of the table was named `Contenuto` as the table name. Not noticing it, I added the DB to the projects anyway.

I noticed that problem on the first run of the app (thrown an exception since you can use the table name as attribute in query), and **edited the DB in the common project**.

Doing this **will not update the Android/iOS DB linked** file.
That was the actual problem in my method I was looking for Testo attribute but was not there.

So when you add the DB as new element to android or iOS projects, remember to set its property to `Always copy`, doing this **will always update the linked DB** when the app is built.